# как правильно сохранять в БД Laravel динамические input

Tags: laravel

т.е которые пользователь может добавить сколько ему нужно и заполнить

сейчас вот есть так

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 relationship_container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="r_name[0]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="r_relationship[0]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="r_name[1]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="r_relationship[1]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="r_name[2]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="r_relationship[2]" class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

```js
let count = $('.relationship_container .row').length;
        
        $(".fa-plus").click(function() {
            let div = '<div class="row">';
            div += '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">';
            div += '<div class="form-group">'
            div += '<input name="r_name[' + count + ']" class="form-control" type="text"></div>';
            div += '</div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">';
            div += '<div class="form-group">';
            div += '<input name="r_relationship[' + count + ']" class="form-control" type="text"></div>';
            div += '</div></div>';
            $('.relationship_container').append(div);
            count++;
        });
```

когда в контроллере считываю почему то не сохраняется

```
class ApplyController extends Controller
{
public function apply_now(Request $request)
    {
    $r_name = $request->input('r_name');

    $r_relationship = $request->input('r_relationship');
    //return $r_name;показывает что это массив ['ttt', 'yyyy', 'rrr']
    //если присвоить значения жестко
    $r_name = 'rrr';
    $r_relationship = 'ttt'; тогда все сохранится

    $apply = new Apply();
    $apply->r_name = $r_name;
    $apply->r_relationship = $r_relationship;

    $apply->save();
   }
}
```

Comment: Так вы что хотите? Вы записываете массив и пытаетесь сохранить в одно оле кучу значений. Надо на каждый элемент массива запись создавать? Тогда по foreach проходите массив и создавайте эту запись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил из массива нужно сделать строку и записать

```
    $r_name = implode($request->input('r_name'), ',');
$apply = new Apply();
   $apply->r_name = $r_name;
  $apply->save();
```